# Google Spreadsheet filter a Range per script

Tags: google-apps-script, filter, google-sheets, date-range

I have created a big list in Google Spreadsheet. To manage the data I used the Standardfilterfunction from the Google menu Data/Filter. Is it possible to use this menu point to a Script? I know the way about the formula "`=Filter`" --> but I must work with a new List.

[image]

The way to sort the range, here's what I've found:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var range = ss.getRange('B2:E10');
ss.setNamedRange("KompletteDaten",range);  
var gRange = ss.getRangeByName("KompletteDaten")
gRange.sort(2);
```

For example: I want to see, with a click on a button, only the line where the value in the column "`Closed`" is done.

Comment: Correct me if this is how to interpret the function you need.

Scenario: You want to filter the items with 'done' in `closed` column, read the items and write the list a new sheet/workbook, either way.

Comment: Hello, i think my description has been misleadingly written. I don´t will create a new tabel. I will work in the same table like the standard-filter-function from the menue "Data/Filter".

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use this menu point to a Script?

To call a script from the Google Sheets UI we could use an image, a custom menu, a custom dialog or a side bar but we can't call a script from the filter dropdown menu.